# Highlight menu item i created with a block in magento

Tags: magento, menu, content-management-system

I explain my problem. I have a running installation of magento, I wanted to change the shop megamenu, so I created a new block with the megamenu. 
Then I set " no " in: include in navigation menu of the main shop category.

Now I have my new menu working but the problem is when I go into the shop page the "shop" button does not get highlighted. How can i fix that?

The shop is here: http://www.ovunque6.it/shop.html

Comment: solved on my own :-)

Comment: Then posting the answer here would help others when they face the same issue.

Comment: i simply reactivated the original theme menu block instead of the standard one.